# Get minimum hours and maximum hours from mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have facility data that have record like below.

```
Id_facility | time_start | time_end
1           | 07:00:00   | 19:00:00
2           | 08:00:00   | 20:00:00
```

I want to get the `lowest time_start` and the `highest time_end` in one query, 
ex: 07:00:00, 20:00:00

my try:

```
SELECT time_start, MIN( TIME_TO_SEC(time_start)), time_end, MAX( TIME_TO_SEC(time_end)) AS mite FROM facility
```

but the result is only return the first row.

How do i get lowest time_start and highest time_end in one query?**

Comment: What output do you want? `SELECT MIN(time_start), MAX(time_end) FROM facility` would get you one row with lowest/highest times.

Comment: @jpw i want get time_start and time_end only, in my trial query, i try to compare for each record. But it fail

Comment: Is this what you want? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41cad/4

Comment: @jpw oh thanks a lot!!! why i make it so complicated if there is simply way

Comment: You use `varchar` for your `time_start` and `time_end` columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this is what you want:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41cad/4)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE facility
    (`Id_facility` int, `time_start` varchar(8), `time_end` varchar(8))
;

INSERT INTO facility
    (`Id_facility`, `time_start`, `time_end`)
VALUES
    (1, '07:00:00', '19:00:00'),
    (2, '08:00:00', '20:00:00')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT MIN( time_start), MAX( time_end) FROM facility
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41cad/4/0)**:

```
| MIN( TIME_START) | MAX( TIME_END) |
|------------------|----------------|
|         07:00:00 |       20:00:00 |
```

Comment: Note that this will only work if the `time_start` and `time_end` columns are `varchar`.

Comment: @isim Yes I know, but it would seem that it worked for the OP. Maybe the data is stored as varchar, or maybe time, I don't know.

Comment: I think the values in his `time_start` and `time_end` columns are wrong. AFAIK, there isn't a time-only type in MySQL.. just in case OP start messaging you again in a few days and says, "*it's not working*" :)

Comment: @isim There is a [time datatype in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html) and my query would work on that too; http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6fb80/1

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get two results? One with the lowest start time, and another with the highest end time?

```
SELECT time_start, time_end
FROM facility
WHERE time_start = MIN( TIME_TO_SEC(time_start))
      OR time_end = MAX( TIME_TO_SEC(time_end))
FROM facility
```